# jQuery.validate display error in a error message box

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm using the follow below to display error message next to each unfilled field. I'd like to simplify things and just have a ErrorBox appear that says "Please fill in all fields" when the submit button is clicked and fields are not filled. `class="required"` is being used on each field type that is required. how would I do this, do I use `showError` ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: $("#form1 div.error")
    });
</script>
```

Comment: maybe that will help http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#demo http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/marketo/

Comment: @Sora i'm looking for a popup dialog error box. I've seen the above examples that print the error in a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Code
```

Displays a message above the form, indicating how many fields are invalid when the user tries to submit an invalid form.

```
$(".selector").validate({
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
  var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
  if (errors) {
    var message = errors == 1
      ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
      : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
    $("div.error span").html(message);
    $("div.error").show();
  } else {
    $("div.error").hide();
  }
}
 })
```

instead of using a div use another jquery library that can display a pop up window with the same error message

Comment: i'm trying to do a dialog popup box. I have no problem displaying the error in a div like in my original post.

Comment: use jquery dialog instead of $("div.error").show(); use $("div.error").dialog(); and that's a link for the api http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

The validate plugin has `invalidHandler: function(e, validator)` which will suit your needs.

A small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/5YHQb/1/

Comment: how would I apply this, I can't find a sold good example for this. is this better than ShowError?

Comment: @acctman: updated code. good question btw. thanks to you, i have a small snippet of my own to show error summary is popup.